# PROPOSED PROOF for: If $p$ is a prime number such that $p|ab$, then $p|a$ or $p|b$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-writing, solution-verification

Since $p|ab$, then $\exists \alpha \in\ \mathbb{Z}$ such that:

$$\alpha p=ab$$

By dividing both sides by $a$, we obtain:

$$(\alpha \div b)p=a \Rightarrow\ p|a \ \ ( \text{Similarly to prove that} \ \ p|b)$$

---

Is this proof comprehensive? Does it fulfill what is required?

Comment: Can you point out where the flaw is?

Comment: If your proof were true, it would show that $p$ would divide both $a$ *and* $b$, for which I am sure you can see counterexamples yourself. With such counterexamples, like $a=p=2$, $b=3$, you can also go through your proof step by step and find which step is wrong.

Comment: As a rule of thumb: you mustn’t divide in $\Bbb Z$. For example $b=3, \alpha=2$ would be very bad.

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg got your point. p would hence divide both integers, right?

Comment: @PrudiiArca thank you!! got it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not complete because it's possible that $b$ might not divide $\alpha$. For example, consider $$p | \alpha p$$ with $p \nmid \alpha$.

Then indeed $\alpha p = \alpha p$ but $\alpha \div p$ is not an integer number.

Comment: Thank you!! But in the example you stated.. don't we get that p|p? Because we obtain p|alpha _or_ p|p and hence the latter is what we obtain using your proposed counterexample

Comment: Most certainly. I was just showing that following the steps you've delineated mechanically doesn't give necessarily the right answer; as others has pointed out, your proof also implies that p divides both a and b, which is false in general.

Comment: Thank you! It is clearer now

Comment: @Omar You can't use the conclusion to prove the conclusion.